# How to open IntelliJ menu actions search

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Blender has a very useful menu invoked by pressing `Spacebar` which allows to find by typing and invoke any function anywhere in any menu of the program.

[image: The Space-menu]

([The Space-menu](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Menus))

Does IntelliJ have the same feature? Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Find Action](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/06/find-action-saves-time/): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]